# ¿Importar fuentes personalizadas a Android Studio para usar en Layouts?

Tags: android, xml

Buenas, como hago uso de fuentes personalizadas en android studio para los Layouts, solo se pueden establecer programaticamente o hay manera de colocarlas directamente al Layout en XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programaticamente puedes hacer uso de fuentes en tu directorio `assets`, debes crear un objeto de tipo `Typeface` a partir de un fichero de fuente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Colocas tu archivo de fuentes en la carpeta assets, puedes colocar una subcarpeta dentro que se llame fonts si gustas para llevar más orden e instancias un objeto `Typeface` así

```
//Definicion de clase de utilidades Fuentes.java por ejemplo

public static Typeface myFont(Context context) {
    return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
}
```

Luego aplicas tu fuente al componente que desees

```
TextView tv = findViewById ....
tv.setTypeface(Fuentes.myFont(this));
```

Lo tedioso de esto es si quieres aplicar la fuente a muchos componentes en tu app.

Para aplicarlas directamente al `Layout`, hasta donde sé `android-typeface-textview` sólo trabaja para `TextView`, además de ello está `deprecated`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes probar [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) tal como se sugiere, no la he probado; pero por su demo veo que puede ser usado directamente al `Layout` mediante un atributo `fontPath` y tanto en `TextViews`, `styles` y `Buttons`, pruebala y nos comentas.

Algunos ejemplos que proveé son los siguientes:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"/>

<CheckBox
    fontPath="fonts/Oswald-Stencbab.ttf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/checkbox_custom"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_bold"
    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="@string/button_defined"/>

<TextView
    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-None.ttf"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/defined_incorrect"/>
```

Comment: Gracias por la info, y lo tendré en cuenta.

Comment: La pregunta era para colocarla directamente desde XML, pero buenoooo......

Comment: @x4mp73r el recurso que recomiendas solo trabaja con `TextView` y además está `deprecated`

Comment: La pregunta decía alguna forma de hacerlo mediante el XML, no programáticamente, eso que respondiste cualquiera lo sabe.

Comment: @x4mp73r siquiera has visto la respuesta completa. ¿Qué quieres puntos? No es lugar para estar realizando ese tipo de comentarios, si quieres te doy mi correo y me escribes tu inconformidad.

Answer (score 1):

Googleando un poco....

Hay una librería que puedes hacer uso de como mencionas, [aquí está](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-typeface-textview):

Así quedaría de esta manera el custom `TextView` que utilizarías:

```
<com.mobsandgeeks.ui.TypefaceTextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="stackoverflow en español"
geekui:customTypeface="fonts/custom_font.ttf" />
```

Comment: ¿Y en que dirección coloco la fuente que importé?